# How do I continue after multiple Tasks without blocking the UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library, busyindicator

In my MVVM application my view model calls 3 different service methods, converts the data from each into a common format and then updates the UI using property notification/observable collections etc.

Each method in the service layer starts a new `Task` and returns the `Task` to the view model. Here's an example of one of my service methods.

```
public class ResourceService
{
internal static Task LoadResources(Action<IEnumerable<Resource>> completedCallback, Action<Exception> errorCallback)
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //... get resources from somewhere
        return resources;
    });

    t.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            errorCallback(task.Exception);
            return;
        }
        completedCallback(task.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    return t;
}
}
```

Here's the calling code and other relevant parts of the view model...

```
private ObservableCollection<DataItem> Data = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();

public ICollectionView DataView
{
    get { return _dataView; }
    set
    {
        if (_dataView != value)
        {
            _dataView = value;
            RaisePropertyChange(() => DataView);
        }
    }
}

private void LoadData()
{
    SetBusy("Loading...");

    Data.Clear();

    Task[] tasks = new Task[3]
    {
        LoadTools(),
        LoadResources(),
        LoadPersonel()
    };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    DataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data);
    DataView.Filter = FilterTimelineData;

    IsBusy = false;
}

private Task LoadResources()
{
    return ResourceService.LoadResources(resources =>
    {
        foreach(var r in resources)
        {
            var d = convertResource(r);
            Data.Add(d);
        }
    },
    error => 
    {
        // do some error handling
    });
}
```

This almost works but there are a couple of small issues.

Number 1: In the call to `SetBusy` at the very beginning, before I start any tasks and before I call `WaitAll`, I set the `IsBusy` property to true. This should update the UI and show the BusyIndicator control but it's not working. I've also tried adding simple string properties and binding those and they're not being updated either. The IsBusy functionality is part of a base class and works in other view models where I don't have more than one Task running so I don't believe there is an issue with the property notification or data binding in the XAML.

All the data bindings seem to be updated after the whole method has completed. I'm not seeing any "first time exceptions" or binding errors in the output Window which is leading me to believe the UI thread is somehow being blocked before the call to WaitAll.

Number 2: I seem to be returning the wrong Tasks from the service methods. I want everything after `WaitAll` to run after the view model has converted all the results from all the service methods in the callbacks. However if I return the continuation task from the service method the continuation never gets called and `WaitAll` waits forever. The strange thing is the UI control bound to the ICollectionView actually displays everything correctly, I assumed this is because Data is an observable collection and the CollectionViewSource is aware of the collection changed events.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to build a continuation that runs when the input tasks all complete.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[3]
{
    LoadTools(),
    LoadResources(),
    LoadPersonel()
};

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, t =>
{
    DataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data);
    DataView.Filter = FilterTimelineData;

    IsBusy = false;
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Note that this becomes simpler if you use C# 5's `await`/`async` syntax:

```
private async void LoadData()
{
    SetBusy("Loading...");

    Data.Clear();

    Task[] tasks = new Task[3]
    {
        LoadTools(),
        LoadResources(),
        LoadPersonel()
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    DataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data);
    DataView.Filter = FilterTimelineData;

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

---

> However if I return the continuation task from the service method the continuation never gets called and WaitAll waits forever

The problem is that your continuation task requires the UI thread, and you're blocking the UI thread in the `WaitAll` call. This creates a deadlock which will not resolve.

Fixing the above should correct this - you'll want to return the Continuation as the Task, as that's what you need to wait for completion - but by using `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll` you free up the UI thread so it can process those continuations.

Note that this is another thing that gets simplified with C# 5.  You can write your other methods as:

```
internal static async Task LoadResources(Action<IEnumerable<Resource>> completedCallback, Action<Exception> errorCallback)
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //... get resources from somewhere
        return resources;
    });
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    errorCallback(task.Exception);
  }

  completedCallback(task.Result);
}
```

That being said, it's typically better to write the methods to return a `Task<T>` instead of providing callbacks, as that simplifies both ends of the usage.

Comment: I've been putting off using the async/await because I'm not sure if it "just works" with WPF Commands and the Prism DelegateCommand. Task.ContinueWhenAll doesn't seem to exist for me, do I need to reference some TPL extensions library?

Comment: @BenCr Sorry -it's TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll.  In general, the await/async stuff works *better* than task continuations with WPF.  The main difference is that you don't have to jump through crazy hoops to handle exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Reed, this seems to be working a lot better. Hopefully someone might be able to provide an explanation for the blocking before WaitAll was called but this has certainly fixed issues 1 and 2. I'll give the async/await stuff a go in the next iteration and see how I get on.

Comment: @BenCR I just edited my post to explain it.  Basically, WaitAll blocks the UI until the tasks complete, bu the tasks need the UI to complete ;)

Comment: @BenCr: Async/await is far easier than using tasks with continuations (and task schedulers from synchronization contexts, etc). If you need an `async` *command*, you could use [`AsyncDelegateCommand` from here](http://blog.mycupof.net/2012/08/23/mvvm-asyncdelegatecommand-what-asyncawait-can-do-for-uidevelopment/).