# Await ForEach - How Do I Wait for Each Iteration To Complete?

Tags: c#

I have a list of URL's `List<string>`. I want to loop through each URL and download the content on the page. The method that downloads the content from a URL is asynchronous. I want to wait for each iteration to complete

```
foreach(string url in urlList)
{
    await DownloadPage(url);
}
```

Download Method:

```
private async Task DownloadPage(string url)
{
    // await Download content using HttpClient
    // Save file
}
```

What's happening at the moment is it's looping through each `ForEach` without waiting for it to complete.

How can I achieve a solution so that it waits on each iteration for the page to download?

Comment: *"it's looping through each `ForEach` without waiting for it to complete"* That code should be waiting.

Comment: This code should be waiting. That's the point of the await. is the DownloadPage returning a completed task?

Comment: I asked a question a while ago which was similar, I had a collection of running tasks and wanted to execute them all and the "continue with" some other task. Here's the answer, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091802/396861

Comment: Unless you do something weird in `DownloadPage` your code should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using the `await` keyword here, you could also call `.Result` on the method call and the task will be sure to be resolved and you will get the result from it right there on the spot. your code would look like so:

```
foreach(string url in urlList)
{
    DownloadPage(url).Result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you need the [`Task.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
// off the top of my head, syntax not guaranteed to be 100% correct :)
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(string url in urlList) 
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(DownloadPage));
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); 
}
```

Comment: Does this launch all Tasks at the same time though? Or will it wait for each iteration to complete? I need to run each iteration one at a time, not in parallel.

Comment: Yes it will start all more or less simultaneously

Comment: There must be something wrong with `DownloadPage()`, the code in the question should wait each iteration. Regardless, your answer does not do what OP wants.

Comment: @Stijn yes going by the original questions code, it should be doing this: start download first page. wait for completion. start download 2nd page. wait. etc.  There is no reason in that code that would stop it from waiting